# Review of this "Bhaddekaratta Sutta - Liberation teachings on an ideal seclusion", and/or info about the author?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, vipassana, meditation-practicalities, meditation-teachers

(Note that this is surely an experimental "question" for the usual use, although not different, just the purpose and circumstances)

Today the Sangha of the eight directions was given, aside of other Dhamma-Gifts, "[Bhaddekaratta Sutta - Liberation teachings on an ideal seclusion](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/lib/authors/dhammajiva/bhaddekaratta_sutta)", teachings by Ven. U. Dhammajīva Mahā Thero (may all also take part in [rejoicing with the merits](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,9261.0.html))

"Lacking" an introduction and review for this gift -- as well as a biography and a picture portraying the author -- my person thought of sharing the possibility to give such information via an answer posted here.

If wishing to make it an unbound gift toward the Sangha, with a complete text and material, feel free to make use of the pages linked for such -- also if looking for discussion on it -- and possibly link that into your answer.

A short summary of the "question":

- A review, criticism, and/or "teaser" for the teachings given in the *Bhaddekaratta Sutta - Liberation teachings on an ideal seclusion* -- links to references elsewhere, or answers of your own posted here.
- Biographical informations about the Ven. Dhammajiva -- links to pictures, relay-able sources -- possibly accessible to make use of it, since something bonded and not released toward Sangha can not really be used

Comment: What is the actual question being asked here? Are you giving your own review of a teaching and/or wanting feedback on it? If so, this is not the right place to do it. Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Lanka I think the question is -- [this publication](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/lib/authors/dhammajiva/bhaddekaratta_sutta) was given to "the Sangha of the eight directions" who put it on the "accesstoinsight.eu" web site. The OP is giving people people an opportunity to add to that, i.e. to post "reviews, criticisms, and/or teasers" from the sutta in question, either their own or links to other peoples' ... and/or "biographical information and/or pictures" of the author, i.e. of Ven. Dhammajiva -- preferably "given" i.e. unencumbered by copyright (because otherwise the OP can't use it).

Comment: @ChrisW. I see, thanks. I will reopen the question.

Comment: @ChrisW There's already an introduction and "about the author" section [here](https://sangham.net/en/lib/authors/dhammajiva/bhaddekaratta_sutta). I'm not sure what really is the question here.

Comment: Closed because it doesn't seem to be a real question. What the question really is, is unclear. The cited document already has an introduction and biography within it. This is not a site to write book reviews, which would in fact be opinion-based.